# Remove value from varchar list

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a varchar column containing a list of comma separated numbers:

```
 listOfNumbers
   1,2,3,4
   11,1,1,3
   4,2,1
   1
```

Now I need to create a function that takes in input a number and remove if from the column.

Example: if the input is 1 the result should be:

```
 listOfNumbers
   2,3,4
   11,3
   4,2
   empty
```

I tried using multiple REPLACE like:

```
declare @listOfNumbers as varchar(max) 
set @listOfNumbers = '1,2,3,1'

select *, REPLACE(REPLACE(listOfNumbers,',1', ''),'1,', '') from 
(
select @listOfNumbers as listOfNumbers
) t1
```

But it's not correct since I will even REPLACE numbers like 11 or 111.

Is there a way to catch all the cases?

Thanks in advance for the responses.

Edit:
I know this is not the correct way to handle this type of data but I don't have a choice over it.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Why don't you use the right model in the first place? Store them in  a separate table which is linked to the main table via foreign-key

Comment: How about finding one of the popular table-valued functions (TVFs) that split a comma-separated string into a column of values, drop the value you don't want, and then corrupt the remainder back into something evil?

Comment: I know this is not the right way to store this kind of data but I don't have any control over it.
I just have to deal with it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to convert the comma-separated list to XML, extract the values from the XML, drop the designated victim, and reassemble whatever is left.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @ListsOfNumbers as Table ( Id Int Identity, BadThing VarChar(256) );
insert into @ListsOfNumbers values
  ( '1,2,3,4' ), ( '11,1,1,3' ), ( '4,2,1' ), ( '1' );
select * from @ListsOfNumbers;

-- Make a new mess.
declare @ValueToDrop as Int = 1;

-- Just to see what's going on: show everything.
select *
  from (
  select Id, BadThing,
    Cast( '<root><csv>' + Replace( BadThing, ',', '</csv><csv>' ) + '</csv></root>' as XML ) as XMLBadThing
    from @ListsOfNumbers ) as PH cross apply
      ( select Val.value( '.', 'integer' ) as Val
          from XMLBadThing.nodes( 'root/csv' ) as SeparatedValues( Val ) ) as OtherPH;

-- Just to see what's going on: without the specified target.
select *
  from (
  select Id, BadThing,
    Cast( '<root><csv>' + Replace( BadThing, ',', '</csv><csv>' ) + '</csv></root>' as XML ) as XMLBadThing
    from @ListsOfNumbers ) as PH cross apply
      ( select Val.value( '.', 'integer' ) as Val
          from XMLBadThing.nodes( 'root/csv' ) as SeparatedValues( Val ) ) as OtherPH
  where Val <> @ValueToDrop;

-- Go from the sample data to regrouped stuff without the target value.  
with BadThings as (
  select Id, BadThing, XMLBadThing, Val
  from (
  select Id, BadThing,
    Cast( '<root><csv>' + Replace( BadThing, ',', '</csv><csv>' ) + '</csv></root>' as XML ) as XMLBadThing
    from @ListsOfNumbers ) as PH cross apply
      ( select Val.value( '.', 'integer' ) as Val
          from XMLBadThing.nodes( 'root/csv' ) as SeparatedValues( Val ) ) as OtherPH
  where Val <> @ValueToDrop )
  select distinct Id, NewBadThing
    from BadThings as BT cross apply
    ( select Stuff( ( select ',' + Cast( Val as VarChar(10) )
        from BadThings where Id = BT.Id order by Val for XML path(''), type).value('.[1]', 'VarChar(max)' ), 1, 1, '' ) as NewBadThing ) as X
```

**UPDATE**

A slightly tidier version of the final query:

```
with BadThings as ( -- @ListsOfNumbers   with the comma-delimited list converted to an XML column.
  select Id, BadThing,
    Cast( '<root><csv>' + Replace( BadThing, ',', '</csv><csv>' ) + '</csv></root>' as XML ) as XMLBadThing
    from @ListsOfNumbers ),
  BadThingValues as ( -- BadThings   with the XML parsed to produce one value per row.
    select Id, BadThing, XMLBadThing, BadThingNodes.XMLNode.value( '.', 'integer' ) as BadThingValue
      from BadThings as BT cross apply
        XMLBadThing.nodes( 'root/csv' ) as BadThingNodes( XMLNode ) )
--  select * from BadThings; -- To see the first step in the CTE use this   SELECT .
--  select * from BadThingValues; -- To see the second step in the CTE use this   SELECT .
  select distinct BTV.Id, BTV.BadThing, Coalesce( CDL.NewBadThing, '' ) as NewBadThing
    from BadThingValues as BTV cross apply
    ( select Stuff( ( select ',' + Cast( BadThingValue as VarChar(10) )
        from BadThingValues
        where Id = BTV.Id and BadThingValue <> @ValueToDrop
        for XML path(''), type).value('.[1]', 'VarChar(max)' ), 1, 1, '' ) as NewBadThing ) as CDL;
```

Comment: This is quite brilliant and it cover all the fringe cases. Can you explain why you need to specify `as SeparatedValues( Val )`?

Comment: @MindedSecurity The result of `.nodes` pretends to be a table returning a column of nodes, hence the poorly named `SeparatedValues( Val )`. I've updated the answer with a somewhat tidier version of the final query that has somewhat more rational object names.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to store values in lists in strings.

Any solution you choose to solve your problem will be dependent on whether the strings are wellformed or not.

Now a simple solution, assuming that you have no whitespaces in your strings, and the seperator always is ',' is

```
select
reverse(
    stuff(
        reverse(
            stuff(
                replace(
                    ','+c+','
                    ,','+cast(@i as nvarchar(max))+','
                    ,','
                    )
                ,1,1,'')
                )
        ,1,1,'')
    )
from 
(values
   ('1,2,3,4')
   ,('11,1,1,3')
   ,('4,2,1')
   ,('1')
) a(c)
```

What I do is that I add a ',' to the start and end of each string.

Then in replace  ',1,' (if you want to remove 1) with ','

This leaves a string with commas at both ends, which you do not want, so I remove the first comma by using "STUFF", then I reverse the result, and remove the first comma using "STUFF", then i reverse the string back, and end up with the result

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I assume that @i = 1 right ?
I still have a problem with duplicate consecutive values on the same string: only one is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little bit of hacking you can play with. Again it's certainly not a wise idea to store data in this format although you could certainly still find this useful outside of the realm of databases.

```
declare @list nvarchar(256) = '1, 2, 1, 3, 4';
declare @value_to_remove nvarchar(16) = '1';

select
    replace(substring(
      replace(
          replace(
            ', ' + replace(@list, ',', ',,') + ',,,',
            ', ' + @value_to_remove + ',',
            ''
          ), ',,', ','),
      3, 256), ',,', ''
    )
```

I wrote this before even seeing the other answer but notice that it does handle adjacent list items. The trick is to double up the commas and of course to include the surrounding commas in the search and replace strings.

You might this alternate version to be clearer. Note that the values in the list can't have any square bracket characters.

```
select
    replace(substring(
      replace(
          replace(
            '[ ' + replace(@list, ',', '][') + ']',
            '[ ' + @value_to_remove + ']',
            ''
          ), '][', ','),
      3, 256), ']', ''
    );
```

Play with both here: http://rextester.com/IHQ53263